# duplicate answers when predicate in more than one field SQL

Tags: sql, database, predicate

I'm so new to this that even the answers on questions similar to my one really don't make any sense to me (I started SQL last week)

I'm trying to list addresses from Table 1 where there are multiple in each address with the same first and surnames (i.e. John Smith and John Smith). I have first names and surnames in separate fields.

I tried

```
SELECT *  
FROM addresses  
WHERE EXISTS (  
    SELECT individuals.FirstName  
    AND individuals.Surname  
    FROM individuals  
    WHERE addresses.AddressID = individuals.AddressID  
    GROUP BY addresses.StreetName  
    HAVING COUNT( * ) >1`
```

but this just gives me a list of every address that has more than one person in it.. 
Can anyone give me a (simpleish) answer that I might get my head around. 
Thanks, Stacey

Comment: Just edited your post to improve formatting, and noticed your SQL is not syntactically correct. Please edit your question with the query you used.

Comment: oh dear, that was the query i used.

Comment: Can you also specify what kind of output you expect? And which one you currently get? It's kind of difficult to see exactly what you are trying to query

Comment: There is at least one closing parenthesis missing. I think the "AND" in the inner SELECT clause was a comma?

Comment: the normal english is just "list addresses where there are two people with the same name" and I am trying to return a list of addresses. I have managed to get the list I was looking for with the solution Marco gave below, by editing to individuals.firstname etc. I haven't seen the CONCAT_WS or using '  ' before though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT 
    a.*

FROM 
    addresses a
        JOIN
    individuals i
    ON a.AddressID = i.AddressID

GROUP BY
    a.StreetName, i.FirstName, i.Surname

HAVING
    COUNT(1) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add

```
individuals.FirstName, individuals.Surname
```

after

```
GROUP BY addresses.StreetName
```

then that should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT addresses.* 
FROM addresses
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT AddressID 
    FROM individuals
    GROUP BY AddressID, FirstName, Surname
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) as tbl1
ON tbl1.AddressID = addresses.AddressID
```

Comment: thanks all - managed to get it to work. I'll learn it all soon enough hopefully.